# When in a For loop with multiple variables, how to write If variable 1 and variable 2 occures at the samt time, skip to next variable in 1st for loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that opens files, and it works great when I want to open all files. But if I don't want to open certain files, depending on combinations of variables in filename, I don't know how to do. I don't quite know what to search for either so my research on the wide web has not been succesful.

I know the attatched code is long, but it's not that complicated, but  where I get stuck is that I dont know how to do. I tried with If.. but the line "Next X" gives error message *"Next without For"*. And if I change the If to "For Z = 2 To 2" I get the error that *"the for variable is already used"*.

So the  question is: How do I prevent to open files with special combinations like when for example X = 2 and Z = 11. (the rest of the combinations can be seen in the code below)

```
Sub OpenFiles_Specified()
'opens all desired files in a folder
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim AllFiles As String

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Single
Dim Z As Integer
Dim i As Integer


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For X = 2 To 6                          '2-12       :Folders(BeamLength)
    For Y = 1 To 1 Step 0.5             '1, 1.5, 2  :Bracings
        For Z = 0 To 3                  '0-3        :Load Cases
            For i = 1 To 1              '1-5        :Iterations

            If Z = 2 Then
                If X = 11 Or X = 10 Or X = 8 Or X = 7 Or X = 5 Or X = 4 Or X = 2 Then
                    Next X
                Else
                    'Do nothing
                End If
            ElseIf Z = 3 Then
                If X = 11 Or X = 9 Or X = 7 Or X = 5 Or X = 3 Then
                    Next X
                Else 
                    'Do nothing
                End If
            Else
                'ok combination
            End If

            ResultFolder = "C:\Beamresults\results"
            AllFiles = Dir(ResultFolder & "\" & "Length" & X & "_Bracing" & Y & "_LoadCase" & Z & "_Iteration" & i & "_.xls")

            Do While AllFiles <> ""
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=ResultFolder & "\" & AllFiles
            AllFiles = Dir

            Loop
            Next i
        Next Z
    Next Y
Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: you can put an opposite comparison before the loop, i.e. `if X<>2 OR Z<>11 then` run the code and past the part you want to skip in case they are both in fact equal close with `End if`

Comment: So, put "if X<>2 OR Z<>11 then" before "For X = 2 To 6"? And "End if" after "Loop"?, and as you can see in the code there are some more combinations aswell, but I guess just adding those to the if you suggested?

Comment: no it has to be after `For Z` as otherwise you "Z" is always 0. if you add it after `for z` and before `for i`, your `end if` must be after `next i` and before `next z`

Comment: just extended my earlier comment, please see above

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem, I used GoTo. I have seen that it is not the most prefered command to use, but it works great for this task.

```
Sub Exclude_unvalid_loadcases()
'opens all desired files in a folder
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim AllFiles As String

Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Single
Dim Z As Integer
Dim i As Integer


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For X = 2 To 6                          '2-12       :Folders
    For Y = 1 To 1 Step 0.5             '1, 1.5, 2  :Bracings
        For Z = 0 To 3                  '0-3        :Load Cases
            For i = 1 To 1              '1-5        :Iterations


            If Z = 2 And X = 2 Then GoTo LastLine
            If Z = 2 And X = 4 Then GoTo LastLine
            If Z = 2 And X = 5 Then GoTo LastLine
            If Z = 2 And X = 7 Then GoTo LastLine
            If Z = 2 And X = 8 Then GoTo LastLine
            If Z = 2 And X = 10 Then GoTo LastLine
            If Z = 2 And X = 11 Then GoTo LastLine

            If Z = 3 And X = 3 Then GoTo LastLine
            If Z = 3 And X = 5 Then GoTo LastLine
            If Z = 3 And X = 7 Then GoTo LastLine
            If Z = 3 And X = 9 Then GoTo LastLine
            If Z = 3 And X = 11 Then GoTo LastLine

            ResultFolder = "C:\Beamresults\results"
        AllFiles = Dir(ResultFolder & "\" & "Length" & X & "_Bracing" & Y & "_LoadCase" & Z & "_Iteration" & i & "_.xls")

            Do While AllFiles <> ""
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=ResultFolder & "\" & AllFiles
            AllFiles = Dir


LastLine:
Loop

            Next i
        Next Z
    Next Y
Next X

End Sub
```